XLOOKUP function to look up values in two or more columns from different workbooks
I am trying to use XLOOKUP function in excel in order to find a value in two ore more different columns placed each one in a different worksheet or workbook.
So the lookup_array should contain multiple columns from different worksheets, and same for the return_array.
I have tried the following syntax using the & (ampersand) operator trying to create a combined lookup_array and similar return_array but it won't work..
=XLOOKUP(R4;'Proj_list 111'!M4:M596&'Proj_list 222'!M4:M596;'Proj_list 111'!U4:U596&'Proj_list 222'!U4:U596;;0;1)

Is there a way to do this?

& is for text. Combine ranges HSTACK or VSTACK is a way.
